# How can I split nested list at a substring?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [['dog===frog', 'cat===dog'], ['bird===bat', 'ball===call']]
```

Where `len(a)` can be as large as needed and `len(a[I])` can be as large as needed..

how can I get out `b = [['dog','frog','cat','dog'],['bird','bat','ball','call']]` ?

I have tried somethings along the line of

```
[' '.join(x).split('===') for x in new_list]
```

and just general list comprehension with .join, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b = [sum([x.split('===') for x in sublist], []) for sublist in a]`

should give you what you want. Works like this:

- `split('===')` makes list from every string
- you then add those using sum: `sum([['dog', 'frog'], ['cat', 'dog']], [])` is basically `['dog', 'frog'] + ['cat', 'dog']`
- `sum([x.split('===') for x in sublist], [])` uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make a split list from all pieces of small list (`['dog===frog', 'cat===dog']`), which is the fed to `sum`
- and it's all wrapped in another comprehension that runs it for every part of your big list `a`

Comment: perfection...and a 1-liner!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
a = [['dog===frog', 'cat===dog'], ['bird===bat', 'ball===call']]
result = [[chunk for chunks in map(lambda e: e.split('='), sub) for chunk in chunks if chunk] for sub in a]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['dog', 'frog', 'cat', 'dog'], ['bird', 'bat', 'ball', 'call']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the results of splitting the strings in a list into a single list

```
from itertools import chain

[list(chain.from_iterable(s.split('===') for s in sub)) for sub in a]
# [['dog', 'frog', 'cat', 'dog'], ['bird', 'bat', 'ball', 'call']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using list comprehension.

`[[word for element in sublist for word in element.split('===')] for sublist in a]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = [['dog===frog', 'cat===dog'], ['bird===bat', 'ball===call']]
a = [ i.split('===') for i in np.array(a).ravel()]
```

Output:

```
[['dog', 'frog'], ['cat', 'dog'], ['bird', 'bat'], ['ball', 'call']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def flatten(seq):
    """list -> list                                                                                                                                                                           
    return a flattend list from an abitrarily nested list                                                                                                                                     
    """
    if not seq:
        return seq
    if not isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return [seq[0]] + flatten(seq[1:])
    return flatten(seq[0]) + flatten(seq[1:])

b=[[j.split("===") for j in i] for i in a]
c=[flatten(i) for i in b]
c
    [['dog', 'frog', 'cat', 'dog'], ['bird', 'bat', 'ball', 'call']]
```